# How to decode bitmap images using python's email class

Tags: python, email, mime

Hello I have python script that takes apart an email from a string. I am using the get_payload(decode=True) function from the email class and it works great for pdf's and jpg's but it does not decode bmp files. The file is still encoded base64 when I write it to disk.

Has anyone come across this issue themselves?

Comment: Does the saved file look the same as the raw message data?

Answer (score 0):

OK so I finally found the problem and it was not related to the python mail class at all. I was reading from a named pipe using the .read() function and it was not reading the entire email from the pipe. I had to pass the read function a size argument and then it was able to read the entire email. So ultimately the reason why my bmp file was not decoded is because I had invalid base64 data causing the get_payload() function to not be able to decode the attatchment.